# How to execute the CSV file multiple times in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

I have a CSV file(containing 2 requests) and I would like to execute JMeter in the below fashion:

```
THREAD 1:
    LoopCount 1
         Request 1
         Request 2
    LoopCount 2
         Request 1
         Request 2
    LoopCount 3
         Request 1
         Request 2
```

My current JMX file looks like below

```
THREAD GROUP(Threads=1, LoopCount=3):
     Loop Controller(LoopCount=forever)
         HTTP Request
         CSV Data Config(Recycle on EOF=False, Stop Thread on EOF=True)
```

But it executes only one time(1 loop). And if I modify Recycle on EOF = True, it executes forever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You have `Stop Thread on EOF=True` which instructs JMeter to stop the thread (virtual user) when the end of file is reached
2. You have [Loop Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller) configured to loop forever which means that your test will never end
3. You have `Recycle on EOF=False` which means that when the last line of the CSV file is reached you will get `<EOF>` value stored in the respective variable for each and every next request

So

- remove this Loop Controller
- and reset CSV Data Set Config to its default settings in terms of recycling / stopping thread on the end of file:

[image]

In the above demo image:

- [__threadNum() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadNum) returns the number of current thread (virtual user)
- `${__jm__Thread Group__idx}` is the [pre-defined variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#predefinedvars) which returns the current loop of the Thread Group

More information: [Using CSV DATA SET CONFIG](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733689-Using-CSV-DATA-SET-CONFIG-Using-CSV-DATA-SET-CONFIG)

Comment: based on your configuration(threads=2, LoopCount=3, Requests in csv file=2). I would expect 12 total requests. User 1 : R1 R2 R1 R2 R1 R2  and User 2 : R1 R2 R1 R2 R1 R2. But your program sends only 6 requests.

Comment: I will not know how many requests in that csv file. so for loop count of 3, each user should execute the csv file 3 times.

But anyway I found a way to do that => I'm actually reading the csv in bean shell preprocessing and calculating the number of requests. then I will stop the thread from beanshell preprocessor itself when it sends all requests.

Comment: Then put the Loop Controller back and set the number of loops to the number of lines in the CSV file, you can calculate it using [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) like `${__groovy(new File('test.csv').readLines().size(),)}`, please avoid using Beanshell for scripting, [since JMeter 3.1 it's recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) language. More information: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)